# Why is "Armed with these facts" the best answer to this SAT transition question?

Tags: american-english, writing-style, expression-choice

I have a question about this transitions question
(it is from the SAT).

The passage starts from here:

> In spite of all compost’s potential uses, however, most of this so-called waste is wasted. According to the Environmental Protection Agency (EPA), over 33 million tons of food waste ended up in US landfills in 2009, along with over 13 million tons of yard debris. Remarkably, more food waste was discarded in landfills in that year than any other substance, including plastics or paper. Even worse than the squandering of this useful resource is the fact that compost in landfills cannot break down due to the lack of necessary air and moisture. As a result, organic material that is sent to landfills contributes to the release of methane, a very potent greenhouse gas.
>
> _______________, cities such as San Francisco and Seattle have instituted mandatory composting laws requiring individuals and businesses to use separate bins for compostable waste. This strict approach may not work everywhere.

In the blank, I have narrowed it down to "Though government regulations vary,"  and "Armed with these facts."

"Armed with these facts" is given as the correct answer, though I am convinced it is "Though government regulations vary," because isn't it contrasting how governmental regulations vary, but some cities still put up regulations?  Why would "Armed with these facts" be correct?

Comment: The most significant word to understand in your question is "transition". Either of the phrases you've identified would make sense in the context of the second paragraph, but only one provides a transition from the first paragraph to the second.

Answer (score 1):

The quoted passage does not have any information about how different jurisdictions have different regulations.

The quoted passage *does* state facts, then explain the measures that two cities have taken using those facts.

The answer key is correct. Using "Armed with these facts" helps explain the transition between one paragraph and the next.